# Codeigniter $this->form->valid

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having issues finding out what $this->form->valid does in Codeigniter controller (given that I don't know what version I'm using)

I cannot find it in User Guide in codeigniter.com and I've looked at form_validation class and form helper already.

Comment: if it is not on User Guide is doesn't exist as a native function...where did you take it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are looking for is here http://www.frankmichel.com/formgenlib/user_guide/installation/download.html

This is an add-on that someone built that either you or someone else added to your codeigniter to allow quicker form functions.

Its not part of the default codeigniter

Also note that the site may look like codeigniters but as far as I can tell they are not affiliated